# self not updating while doing a recursion

Tags: python, dataframe, recursion, self

```
class Node:

   def __init__(self, x, y, min_leaf=5, class_weight=None, max_depth=5, depth=0):
       self.x = x
       self.y = y
       self.node_right = None
       self.node_left = None
       self.min_leaf = min_leaf
       self.class_weight = class_weight
       self.max_depth = max_depth
       self.depth = depth
       self.numOfSamples = len(y)
       self.target_labels_count = [y.tolist().count(0),y.tolist().count(1)]
       self.splitFeature = ""
       self.featureList = x.columns
       self.giniGain = 0

   def grow_tree(self):

       def building_x(lst_idx):
           if (len(lst_idx)) == 0:
               return None
           else:
               df1 = self.x.iloc[lst_idx]
               df2 = self.y.iloc[lst_idx]
               return df1, df2

       def grow_tree_recursive(node,depth):
           # print(node.x)
           # print(node.y)
           if depth==2: return
           max_gini = 0
           left_split_data = None
           right_split_data = None
           for feature in list(node.featureList):
              temp_feature_value,temp_gini,temp_left_node,temp_right_node,
              temp_feature_name = self.find_best_split(feature)
            # print(temp_feature_value,temp_gini,temp_left_node,temp_right_node,temp_feature_name)
            if max_gini < temp_gini:
                max_gini = temp_gini
                left_split_data = temp_left_node
                right_split_data = temp_right_node
                self.splitFeature = temp_feature_name

        if max_gini==0: return
        self.giniGain = max_gini

        x_left,y_left = building_x(left_split_data)
        x_right,y_right = building_x(right_split_data)
        self.node_left = grow_tree_recursive(Node(x_left,y_left),depth+1)
        self.node_right = grow_tree_recursive(Node(x_right,y_right),depth+1)


    return grow_tree_recursive(self,0)

def find_best_split(self, var_idx):
    print(self.x)
    dict1 = {}

    for i in self.x[var_idx]:
        if (i not in dict1):
            dict1[i] = (0, [], [])
    for key in dict1:
        lhs = []
        rhs = []
        for i in range(len(self.x[var_idx])):
            if (self.x[var_idx][i] <= key):
                lhs.append(i)
            else:
                rhs.append(i)
        if (len(lhs) >= self.min_leaf and len(rhs) >= self.min_leaf):
            dict1[key] = (self.get_gini_gain(lhs, rhs), lhs, rhs)
        else:
            dict1[key] = (0,[],[])
    # max_gini=max (dict1.values(),key=lambda x:x[0])
    # print(dict1)
    max_gini = max(dict1.items(), key=lambda x: x[1][0])
    return max_gini[0], max_gini[1][0], max_gini[1][1], max_gini[1][2], var_idx
```

Hi all,

I'm trying to write a recursion function (grow_tree_recursive) and I give it anytime a new node and a number. when im calling it in the second time it get the new node just fine but when I'm calling the self.find_best_split(feature) and printing self.x (which give me a DataFrame) I get the DataFrame of the previous Node. So, basiclly I'm not advance in the recursion at all and I don't know how to fix this. any suggestions?

Comment: Can you check the indentation on the code you posted?

Comment: When you recurse it changes the value of `node`, but not `self`.

Comment: Maybe you want `node.find_best_split(feature)`

Comment: @Barmar it doesn't work, when I change it to node.find_best_split(feature) the find_best_split still using self and it seems that the self there not changing too.

Comment: @slothrop yea I checked and the indentation is fine

Comment: What method is `return grow_tree_recursive(self,0)` in? Its indentation doesn't seem to allow it to be part of any of the methods.

Comment: @slothrop its calling the recursion function for the first time and its work cause im getting into the function

Comment: If it works, then the indentation in the file on your machine must be different from what you've pasted into Stack Overflow. Because in the code you pasted here, `return grow_tree_recursive(self, 0)` isn't part of the `grow_tree` method.

Comment: @slothrop now i see that the code here doesnt have the right identation but in my program its fine and its inside grow tree. my bad here

Comment: Edit the question and fix the indentation. Regarding my comment above, I don't really understand the algorithm you're trying to implement, so it was just a guess. It's not clear how the node you're calling the original method on relates to the nested nodes you're creating.